# javascript Rock-paper-scissor program that stops at a required no of points reached either by the user or pc?

Tags: javascript

this is my first question on stackoverflow and just entering the world of programing and i am trying to write a javascript program  that stops at the required no of points reached either by the user or by the computer.i am presently learning it in codacademy i just can build the game simply to display who wins in one trial.but cant figure out why is it not working when the required no of points are reached,either by the user or computer. `enter code here,ignore the indentation please.

```
    var userPoints=0;
    var systemPoints=0;
    var points=prompt("Enter the no of points for the game to be played");
    while(points>=userPoints || points>=systemPoints){
var user=prompt("enter rock or paper or scissor").toUpperCase();
var system=Math.random();
if(system>0&& system<0.34){
    system="ROCK";
}
else if(system>=0.37&& system<0.67){
    system="PAPER"
}
else{
    system="SCISSOR"
}
console.log("the user choice is"+" "+user);
console.log("the system choice is"+" "+system);
var compare=function(choice1,choice2){
    if(choice1===choice2){
        console.log("it's a tie");
    }
    else if(choice1==="ROCK"){
        if(choice2==="SCISSOR"){
            return "user wins";
            userPoints=userPoints+1;
        }
        else{
            return "system wins";
            systemPoints=systemPoints+1;
        }
    }
    else if(choice1==="PAPER"){
        if(choice2==="Rock"){
            return "user wins";
            userPoints=userPoints+1;
        }
        else{
            return "system wins";
            systemPoints=systemPoints+1;
        }
    }
    else if(choice1==="SCISSOR"){
        if(choice2==="PAPER"){
            return "user wins";
            userPoints=userPoints+1;
        }
        else{
            return "system wins";
            systemPoints=systemPoints+1;
        }
    }
    console.log("user points are"+userPoints);
console.log("system points are"+systemPoints);
};compare(user,system);
```

}

Comment: In general, you should try to cut down your posted code to the minimal amount required to demonstrate the problem - posting a big block and then asking what's broken rarely gets good answers.

Comment: thanks @nrabinowitz as i had already mentioned i am a newbie here anyway thanks for your suggestion.ill keep that in mind next time and i am afraid i cant do so in this as i dont know where the actual error is..!!

Comment: In my experience, making the effort to locate the minimum code required to reproduce the error often allows you to debug the error yourself :). If you aren't willing to do it, probably SO users won't be either.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this line:

```
(points >= userPoints || points >= systemPoints)
```

You probably want an "&&" instead of "||".  As it stands, as long as the user OR the system is below the max number of points, it continues.  You want it to only continue when both are under the max number of points (because as soon as one of them is over, the game should be over.)

Secondly, when you're doing your comparisons:

```
if(choice2==="SCISSOR"){
    return "user wins";
    userPoints=userPoints+1;
}
```

You're returning before updating userPoints, so userPoints never changes.  You should reverse those lines (in each comparison where you're doing that.)

If you're using a browser such as Chrome or IE (and probably others as well) you can debug your code in the developer console (F12) by setting breakpoints and stepping through it...that would allow you to quickly spot problems like the second one.

Comment: Thanks @Beska u said it right but inspite of doing so also the code is not working.

Comment: @PrudhviReddy Added a second issue.